# Regarding RETRY value of WorkerResult of WorkManager

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler, android-workmanager

I am using WorkManager class for a task that I want my app to do at specific time. My Worker class goes like below.

```
@Override
public Result doWork(){
    downloadUpdates();
    return Result.SUCCESS;
}
```

I created this work with OneTimeWorkRequest like below.

```
Constraints.Builder builder = new Constraints.Builder();
builder.setRequiresCharging(true);
OneTimeRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(DownloadWorker.class)
    .setConstraints(builder.build()).build();
workManager.enqueue(request);
```

Now when I test this Worker, if phone is not being charged the work just gets postponed (i.e. retried) until phone is connected. But I suppose if result is `RETRY`, then it should just retry when phone is connected, otherwise just hold.

Since I there is not much documentation regarding this BackOffPolicy, can anyone tell me how does RETRY work and how many times it retries and when does it retry?

Comment: Were you able to learn anything about this? I am wondering the same.